# While Reviewing, What to do when someone gives an algorithm in Pseudocode and asks it to be writing in given language?

Tags: discussion, code

What do the guidelines say about asking to translate pseudo-code into a given language? Is it against the guide lines? If it is or if it isn't, should it be, or should it not be? (I can think of good arguments either way). And in the case which it is not acceptable, what should be done?

So I was reviewing the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098125/how-can-i-write-this-codeimage-processing-in-matlab
which basically asks for translating pseudo-code into Matlab code.

Is this currently an acceptable question?
Should it be an acceptable question? I mean, after all, it **is** a programming question. And it **is** a very clearly defined question. But on the other hand it seems like the asker didn't put much effort into trying to figure it out for themselves first.

And in any case, what should be the proper course of action for such a case?

Comment: It has been dealt with. It's too broad. Just having pseudo code doesn't make it well defined since there will be any number of adequate implementations. It doesn't help in this case that the OP says he doesn't have time to learn: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Ya, I know it has been dealt with, but I would be interested in hearing the general perspective on this for the future.